# How to create a XMLHttpRequest FormData form object

Tags: javascript, json, spring, xmlhttprequest, jackson

I have a form that has files in it so i am using XMLHttpRequest to handle the sending of the data.

What i am trying to do is to be able to send objects that will be parsed by jackson on the server side. just like you do with json.

For example:

> ```
> {
> "number": 123,
> "string": "Hello World",
> "object": {
>     "a": "b"
> }
> ```

}

So i want to create "object". from what i know i can only do "number" and "string" with

```
 formData.append("string", "Hello World");
```

May be there is a way to format it?

when i just append some JSON formated object i get this as a result:

> ```
>     var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("upload-form"));
>      element= {};
>      element.id = 2;
>      element.type = "dfsdf";
>      element.url = "sdfsdff";
>      element.version = "asdasd";
>      arrayOfelement[0] = framework;
>      oData.append("file", this.myfile.getFile());
>      oData.append("frameworks",JSON.stringify(arrayOfelement))
>      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
>      xhr.open('POST', 'design', true);   
>      xhr.onload = function(e) { 
>         console.log("upload finished");
>       };
>      console.debug("sending form data", oData);
>      xhr.send(oData);
>
>
>
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVWNBucDMZSIlUcXY
> ```
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="arrayOfElements"
>   {"0":{"id":2,"type":"dfsdf","url":"sdfsdff","version":"asdasd"}}

which is clearly not going to be parsed into anything on the server side.

Comment: Your `WebKitFormBoundary` example doesn't quite match your javascript, but presuming the JSON string makes it server-side in approximately the form you described, in what way is it clearly "not going to be parsed into anything on the server side"?  You tagged this question as Jackson, so I assume your server-side is Java.  Are you trying to figure out how to parse POST data and JSON parse a POST string using Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

To send an Javascript object via form data with XMLHttpRequest, you'll need to JSON stringify it:

```
var obj = {
    "number": 123,
    "string": "Hello World",
    "object": {
        "a": "b"
    }
}
formData.append(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify